# very well comparable

Tags: word-usage

Is "very well comparable" correct?
Example: In the short story character A is very well comparable with character B. because both of them have a similar lifestyle.

=> If it is correct, can you say "comparable *to*" as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend leaving out 'very well', because this phrase describes the degree or the extent to which the characters are comparable.

'Comparable' has a similar meaning to 'similar' and 'alike', but unlike those alternatives it doesn't take degrees. Two characters can be 'more alike' or 'very similar', for example, but things cannot be 'more comparable' or 'very comparable'. They are either comparable or they are not.

If you want to intensify it, try 'closely comparable'.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer the phrase

> Easily comparable

to 'very well comparable'. But still I don't feel like this expresses what you want it to. Two people could be easily comparable because of how much they **differ**. I'd suggest something like:

> They were [akin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/akin) to one another

You could also consider 'they were [analogies](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/analogy) of one another', or even just 'they were *similar*'.

Comment: That should be "analogous" not analogies

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I'd rephrase your sentence to `In the short story character A is very well comparable to character B.`

As for the usage of  [very well](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/very-well)

An example would be

```
“They had a very well thought out and detailed plan,” says Masood.
```